# English word for the nature of thumb bending backwards?

Tags: single-word-requests

One of my friend used to bend his thumb backwards. I wonder, is there any word in English to call the nature of **thumb bending backwards**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are referring to "[**Hitchhiker's thumb**](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=Hitchhiker%27s%20thumb&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)"

Comment: Thanks @tenfour, Now, i've seen the Hitchhiker page in wikipedia, obviously that's what i expected. **Accepted** and **+1** for the help:-)

Comment: @VijinPaulraj But was your question about the thumb bending backwards at right angles at its _top_ joint or at its base joint (and touching the forearm)?

Comment: @coleopterist: It wasn't very obvious from the original question, but, judging by his enthusiasm here, I believe the O.P. was more interested in top-jointed hypermobile thumbs. :^)

Comment: @tenfour Gawd it's called "distal hyperextensibility of the thumb", what's wrong with you

Answer (score 6):

A popular term for those with this remarkable talent, not just in the thumb but elsewhere too, is *double-jointed*, but it's probably anatomically inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks @Barrie. But double-jointed closely related to **hypermobility**. Is there any word that only specify the bend of thumb?

Comment: Sorry, none that I know.

Comment: Yeah, you call it a double-jointed thumb :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the term *double-jointed*, you could use the term ***[loose joints](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/hypermobility/AN01646)***.  The medical community uses the word ***[hypermobility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypermobility)*** to explain this condition, which includes the ability to "bend your thumbs to your forearms."

From [medicinenet.com](http://www.medicinenet.com/hypermobility_syndrome/article.htm):

[image]

Like Barrie, I don't know of any term related specifically to the thumb, but I did find more than 9,000 hits on Google for "hypermobility of the thumb," and 1,200 for "hypermobile thumb," including some from medical literature.

Comment: Could we really call that as an "ability" ('includes the ability to ...')? It seems to me like  an abnormal "disfunction".

Comment: @Carlo_R.: **ability** (n.): _the capacity to do something_.  Yup, you can call it an ability :^)

Comment: Lol, then I'm going to vote up your answer.

Comment: @Carlo: I'm no doctor, so I won't say this emphatically, but I think **hypermobile thumb** might be the best the O.P. will be able to get.  BTW, thanks for the "thumbs-up."